# WSO2 ESB cluster not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 product. I have setup WSO2 ESB cluster. Servers comes up nicely but configuration done on server1 doesn't gets reflected to server2, say, I created datasource on server1, but it doesn't shows up on second server in cluster.

Comment: `I have setup WSO2 ESB cluster` are you sure you did it well? And - there are artifacts which are clustered (sequences, mediations, endpoints, .. mostly look under the repository/deployment/server) and things which are static to the servers (datasources, listeners, ...)

Comment: so far I have done basic setup and have sync'ed "repository/deployment/server" , but datasource created doesn't seems to be present in this path. I am refering to below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile#ClusteringtheESBProfile

Comment: I believe datasource config (jdbc) is not clustered. If you need some way of dynamically configure the datasource, you could use some CICD deployment tool (Puppet, Ansible, ..) to update the master-datasources.xml (and restart the instances)

Comment: new datasource created is not updated in master-datasource.xml, rather on searching it is found in below places:

Binary file ./solr/data/index/_4e_Lucene50_0.tim matches
Binary file ./solr/data/index/_4e.fdt matches

Here, registry mounted is shared between two servers.